# Mark minimum and maximum values as shaded dots?

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframes I'm plotting through, plotting temperature and humidity values on a line plot. I want to mark the the maximum and minimum temperature using a shaded dot. I'm able to mark it the max and min using:

```
plt.axhline(dataframe.temp.max())
```

But I don't want the lines, but rather the dot so as to be able to see the max and min values clearer. Here's the code I'm working with:

```
for dataframe in li:
    plt.rcParams['font.family'] = 'Nimbus Sans'
    plt.style.use('ggplot')
    plt.ylim(0,110)   
    plt.rc('xtick', labelsize=15)
    plt.rc('ytick', labelsize=15)
    plt.xticks(fontsize=20)
    plt.yticks(fontsize=20)
    plt.figure(figsize=(50,30))

    plt.plot(dataframe['time'], dataframe['temp'], marker='o', color='b', label='Temperature')
    plt.axhline(dataframe.temp.max())
    plt.axhline(dataframe.temp.min())
    plt.plot(dataframe['time'], dataframe['H'], marker='o', color='c', label='Humidity')
    plt.axhline(y=data_total_avg_temp, color='r', linestyle='-', linewidth=5.0, label='Avg. Temp.')
    plt.axhline(y=data_total_avg_hum, color='k', linestyle='-', linewidth=5.0, label='Avg. Hum.')
    leg = plt.legend(loc=2, prop={'size': 25})
    plt.xlabel('Time', weight='bold', fontsize=20)
    plt.ylabel('Temperature and Humidity', weight='bold', fontsize=20)
    plt.title('Site Comparison of Hourly Temperature and Humidity Values', fontsize=30)
```

Is there anyway to mark a shaded dot, or some other way to make the max and min values stand out more so that they are more easily seen?